# Can't log into Openstack Dashboard

Tags: juju, openstack

Newbie here.

I've just installed the single server Openstack on a Dell R410 server running 14.04 TLS Server using these instructions: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/clouddocs/installer/en/single-install.html.

The openstack-installer Dashboard shows every service as running and gives me the URL, login and password for the Openstack Dashboard, but when attempting to log in I see "An error occurred authenticating. Please try again later."

I've attempted changing the password using: "JUJU_HOME=~/.cloud-install/juju juju set keystone admin-password=password" based on the recommendation of someone in the Ubuntu Solutions Engineering team, and although the password change takes place, the problem persists. I've tried looking at other similar questions on this forum ([Can't access OpenStack dashboard](https://askubuntu.com/questions/295580/cant-access-openstack-dashboard) and [Failed to install OpenStack Dashboard](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107211/failed-to-install-openstack-dashboard?rq=1)) but neither one of them gave me any ideas. The first one references a "local.conf"  file which I can't locate anywhere.

Any guidance appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Neither the most "juju"an way, nor the most elegant, but you can try reseting the admin password from command line. Check out this link:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16768272/openstack-change-admin-password-for-the-dashboard

It says this:

> ```
> $ export OS_SERVICE_TOKEN=$servicetoken(/etc/keystone/keystone.conf)
> $ export OS_SERVICE_ENDPOINT=$http://ipoftheserver/v2.0 then use this syntax
> ```
>
> to change the password
>
> ```
> $ keystone user-password-update --pass <password> <user id>
> ```

For the newer versions of OpenStack, use the "openstack" command instead of "keystone".

Alternatively, you can also set the *admin_token* on the keystone.conf.